# How to Throw FileNotFoundException from Process.Start

Tags: c#, file, exception, process, system.diagnostics

I am trying to call `Process.Start()` on an executable. If the file cannot be found, it should be copied into the required location and then try again.

According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb(v=vs.110).aspx), `Process.Start()` can throw a `FileNotFoundException` when `The file specified in the startInfo parameter's FileName property could not be found.`

Based on that, the following would seem like a reasonable approach:

```
try
{
    Process.Start(@"C:\users\Angus.McAngerson\desktop\IT Self Help.exe");
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
{
    File.Copy(@"Z:\Unused\Apps\IT Support App\IT Self Help.exe", @"C:\users\Angus.McAngerson\desktop");
    Process.Start(@"C:\users\Angus.McAngerson\desktop\IT Self Help.exe", "vdi");
}
```

However, the `Start()` in the `try` block only ever throws a **`Win32Exception`**:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll
>
> Message: The system cannot find the file specified
>
> ErrorCode: -2147467259
>
> NativeErrorCode: 2

I tried changing the `try` code to:

```
var procsi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\users\Angus.McAngerson\desktop\IT Self Help.exe");
Process.Start(procsi);
```

But with the same results. I also tried changing the BuildPlatform to `x86`, `x6` and `Any CPU` but without any difference.

Why is this happening? How can I throw a `FileNotFoundException`?

---

#### Update

The documentation states:

**FileNotFoundException:**

> The file specified in the startInfo parameter's FileName property could not be found.

In the case above, the file cannot be found, yet the code throws a different exception. That is at least very misleading if not completely untrue.

The only explanation I can think of is that the program tries to run the file without checking whether it exists. This is fair enough, but then in what scenario would `FileNotFoundException` ever even happen?

Is this an error in the documentation?

Comment: What is the Win32Exception telling you? What's the message, the error code, etc?

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne I updated my question

Comment: is it a  permissions issue are you running from a network drive?which OS are you working on?

Comment: @Rohit It is not a permissions issue - the file is not in that location, but when it is I can run it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.win32exception(v=vs.110).aspx

It will show you that you'll get the Win32Exception when trying to open an executable that doesn't exist.

So actually, your code seems to be functioning fine.

But if you **really** want a FileNotFoundException, then you're gonna have to do some checks yourself before running the process and throw the exception yourself.

```
if(!File.Exists(@"C:\users\Angus.McAngerson\desktop\IT Self Help.exe"))
{
     throw new FileNotFoundException("This file was not found.");
}
```

#### Edit

It does seem as though there may be an error in the documentation as I can't get it to throw the `FileNotFoundException` either, even though it claims to be able to.

So, you can either handle the Win32Exception or do what I suggested above.

Maybe someone else can shed light on this?

Comment: I think I reported it to Microsoft (at the bottom of the page) but I have no idea if that has any impact!

Answer (score 3):

It's really not a good idea to execute statements in catch unless they are related to exception tracking.

I dont see why you cant use [**File.Exists**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx) (since you intend to do nothing with FileNotFoundException ). If we rewrite your code then it would be:

```
if (File.Exists(@"C:\users\Angus.McAngerson\desktop\IT Self Help.exe"))
{
    Process.Start(@"C:\users\Angus.McAngerson\desktop\IT Self Help.exe");
}
else
{
    File.Copy(@"Z:\Unused\Apps\IT Support App\IT Self Help.exe", @"C:\users\Angus.McAngerson\desktop\IT Self Help.exe");
    Process.Start(@"C:\users\Angus.McAngerson\desktop\IT Self Help.exe", "vdi");
}
```

Comment: I do not "intend to do nothing with FileNotFoundException" - the question is about how/why the exceptions are thrown as they are

Comment: I thought its about right coding practices..sorry my bad

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at the documentation for [Process.Start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s(v=vs.110).aspx) you will notice that there is a table of exception conditions including:

**Win32Exception** - An error occurred when opening the associated file.

**FileNotFoundException** - The PATH environment variable has a string containing quotes.

Looks like it's behaving correctly to me even if the exceptions are a little misleading

Comment: Seems you are correct if you follow that link for `Process.Start(string)`, but if you check my link `Process.Start(StartInfo)` then it doesn't mention anything of the sort - very misleading!

Comment: Actually... it does... (the table actually contains _a lot_ more information...) still just as misleading though :)  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It literally says: `FileNotFoundException - The file specified in the startInfo parameter's FileName property could not be found.` Isn't that exactly what is happening in my scenario? Does the program try to run the file before checking if it exists?

Comment: Ha! Yes you're right :P I would suggest filing that as a documentation bug as it's clearly not true